# HTML text box implementation

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, textbox, htmltext

What do I need to do to implement a text box in vb.net (like the one I'm typing to post the question in Stackoverflow) where I can type text and format it in **bold** (for example), but that will appear in 'bold' in the same text box I'm typing?

Thanks

Comment: And for your next trick, you'll carve a piece of wood into a circle and fit four of them to a vehicle? :)   Been done many times - e.g. http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "rich text editor" for ASP.NET.  There are *many* available, some easier to use than others.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be looking for a rich text editor. THere are a number of jQuery plugins that can do this.

Here is a handfull: http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/rich-text-editor

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after a **[WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)** editor, which most of them use an `<iframe>` to do this.

Have a look at the following:

**[tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)**

**[ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)**